# Redirect Mac Safari and Mac Chrome to another webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to redirect Mac visitors to a different website. How can I do this?

~Thanks, Calo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse [`User-Agent`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string to find keywords Macintosh and Safari or Chrome.

But this won't give you guaranteed results, as user can change User-Agent in most of the modern browsers.